# toggle show/hide div with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hopefully this is an easy question. I have a `div` that I want to toggle hidden/shown with a button

```
<div id="newpost">
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Look at [jQuery Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id='content'>Hello World</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
```

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

For versions of jQuery 1.7 and newer use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#hideshow').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('#content').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

For reference, kindly check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vVsAn/1/)

Comment: Now .live() is deprecated in 1.7,and removed in 1.9 so in new versions you can use .on()   (for details https://api.jquery.com/on/ )

Comment: How do you set this to hide by default?

Edit: Figured it out, just added the toggle before the code that catches the button push.

Comment: How about w/o jQuery? Everyone can do it with jQ

Comment: I suppose `toggle('show')` is a typo (that some have blatantly copied and pasted into other answers) because only `'slow'` and `'fast'` are accepted strings for duration. It works nonetheless because I think any invalid string will default to `'slow'`. https://jsfiddle.net/d5y06e6o/

Comment: @simonr2 can you elaborate on what you did to make this hide by default?

Answer (score 144):

**Pure JavaScript:**

```
var button = document.getElementById('button'); // Assumes element with id='button'

button.onclick = function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('newpost');
    if (div.style.display !== 'none') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

#### SEE DEMO

**jQuery**:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
    // assumes element with id='button'
    $("#newpost").toggle();
});
```

#### SEE DEMO

Comment: Hi, any idea how to make it toggle with a nice fadein/fadeout?

Comment: @deemeetree: You could pass `'slow'` to `toggle`. If you're using the pure JS solution let me know and I can come up with something for that

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew I also found that in the new jQuery there's fadeToggle

Comment: Mine doesn't come back in when I click the button again, I've done exactly what you've done on JFiddle...  Do you know of any way to fix that?

Comment: @BarryDoyle: I'd have to see the code... You might be better off starting a new question, just make sure you include the code you're having trouble with and if possible include an example of the problem you're seeing

Comment: I was checking out other questions and I came across an answer in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808112/jquery-toggle-function-not-working ...  Apparently it's because the new versions of JQuery don't support toggle anymore.

Comment: @BarryDoyle: Actually, [toggle-event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) was deprecated in 1.8. The way this answer uses [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) is still available, see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/KpFRb/532/

Comment: any idea how to make a custom element with .show() and .hide() on it, e.g. MyElement extends HTMLElement ... ?

Comment: when the original element has display: none, it will have to click twice to display it

Answer (score 41):

Since toggling using `style` like:

```js
myElement.style.display = someBoolState ? "block" : "none"
```

is a really bad idea, here are some examples in JS, jQuery, HTML, CSS:

## JavaScript [.classList.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
const elToggle  = document.querySelector("#toggle");
const elContent = document.querySelector("#content");

elToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  elContent.classList.toggle("is-hidden");
});
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content" class="is-hidden">Some content...</div>
```

The beauty of the above is that the styling is purely handled where it should, and that's in your stylesheet. Also, by removing the `.is-hidden` class your element will regain its original *`display`* mode, being it `block`, `table`, `flex`, or whatever.

## jQuery .toggle()

[`.toggle()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)
[`.fadeToggle()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/)
[`.slideToggle()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){
  $("#content").toggle();                 // .fadeToggle() // .slideToggle()
});
```

```css
#content{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content">Some content...</div>
```

## jQuery - Toggle [`.toggleClass()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

`.toggle()` toggles an element's `display` `"block"/"none"` values

```js
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){
  $("#content").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
#content{
  display:none;
}
#content.show{
  display:block; /* P.S: Use `!important` if missing `#content` (selector specificity). */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content">Some content...</div>
```

## HTML5 - Toggle using `<summary>` and `<details>`

(unsupported on IE and Opera Mini)

```html
<details>
  <summary>TOGGLE</summary>
  <p>Some content...</p>
</details>
```

## HTML - Toggle using `checkbox`

```css
[id^=toggle],
[id^=toggle] + *{
  display:none;
}
[id^=toggle]:checked + *{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label for="toggle-1">TOGGLE</label>

<input id="toggle-1" type="checkbox">
<div>Some content...</div>
```

## HTML - Switch using `radio`

```css
[id^=switch],
[id^=switch] + *{
  display:none;
}
[id^=switch]:checked + *{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<label for="switch-1">SHOW 1</label>
<label for="switch-2">SHOW 2</label>

<input id="switch-1" type="radio" name="tog">
<div>1 Merol Muspi...</div>

<input id="switch-2" type="radio" name="tog">
<div>2 Lorem Ipsum...</div>
```

## CSS - Switch using `:target`

(just to make sure you have it in your arsenal)

```css
[id^=switch] + *{
  display:none;
}
[id^=switch]:target + *{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#switch1">SHOW 1</a>
<a href="#switch2">SHOW 2</a>

<i id="switch1"></i>
<div>1 Merol Muspi ...</div>

<i id="switch2"></i>
<div>2 Lorem Ipsum...</div>
```

---

### Animating class transition

If you pick one of JS / jQuery way to actually toggle a `className`, you can always add animated transitions to your element, here's a basic example:

```js
const elToggle  = document.querySelector("#toggle");
const elContent = document.querySelector("#content");

elToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
  elContent.classList.toggle("is-hidden");
});
```

```css
#content {
  display: inline-flex; /* or whatever */
  transition: 0.6s;
}

.is-hidden {
  position: relative;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<button id="toggle">TOGGLE</button>
<div id="content" class="is-hidden">Some Togglable content...</div>
```

Comment: You cannot `display: none` element with transitions

Comment: @Green no you cannot. That's the reason of the animated example.

Comment: Hi Sir @Roko C. Buljan is there a way to show the div initially in CSS - Switch using :target toggle please help I really need that.Thanks.

Comment: @ProgrammingHobby absolutely, if you want to make "Default open" one of the above containers (that use `:target` toggle method) simply add the desired *hash* ID to the page URI i.e: `index.html#switch1` - and see the Element ID switch1 open right away. You can also manipulate the URL object  using JS `URL.hash` - if needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan Thank you so much sir.Have a nice day.You answer was great and I have used that in many of mine projects.Thanks for that.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a plain Javascript way of doing toggle:

```
<script>
  var toggle = function() {
  var mydiv = document.getElementById('newpost');
  if (mydiv.style.display === 'block' || mydiv.style.display === '')
    mydiv.style.display = 'none';
  else
    mydiv.style.display = 'block'
  }
</script>

<div id="newpost">asdf</div>
<input type="button" value="btn" onclick="toggle();">
```

Comment: Nice, plain JavaScript solution. I would just recommend that the input type be a button rather than submit since submit will post the form...

Answer (score 1):

Try with opacity

```css
div { transition: all 0.4s ease }
.hide { opacity: 0; }
```

```html
<input onclick="newpost.classList.toggle('hide')" type="button" value="toggle">

<div id="newpost">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I hide and show content using a class. changing the class to nothing will change the display to block, changing the class to 'a' will show the display as none.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
  background-color:#777777;
  }
block1{
  display:block; background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px; margin:20px;
  }
block1.a{
  display:none; background-color:black; color:white; padding:20px; margin:20px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID').setAttribute('class', '');">Open</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('ID').setAttribute('class', 'a');">Close</button>
<block1 id="ID" class="a">
<p>Testing</p>
</block1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hideshow').click(function(){
    $('#content').toggle('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

And the html

```
<div id='content'>Hello World</div>
<input type='button' id='hideshow' value='hide/show'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following:

`mydiv.style.display === 'block' = (mydiv.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');`