# How can I hide/show a div when a button is clicked?

Tags: html, button, hide, show

I have a `div` that contains a register wizard, and I need hide/show this `div` when a button is clicked.
How can I do this?

Below I show you the code.

Thanks :)

```
  <div id="wizard" class="swMain">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#step-1">
            <label class="stepNumber">1</label>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-2">
            <label class="stepNumber">2</label>
        </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-3">
            <label class="stepNumber">3</label>
         </a></li>
      <li><a href="#step-4">
            <label class="stepNumber">4</label>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="step-1"> 
        <h2 class="StepTitle">Perfil</h2>
        <table cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" align="center">
            <tr>
                  <td align="center" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>        
            <tr>
                  <td align="right">Username :</td>
                  <td align="left">
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="" class="txtBox">
                  </td>
                  <td align="left"><span id="msg_username"></span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                  <td align="right">Password :</td>
                  <td align="left">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" class="txtBox">
                  </td>
                  <td align="left"><span id="msg_password"></span>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>                                          
       </table>               
    </div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use JQuery. You need to set-up a click event on your button which will toggle the visibility of your wizard div.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
    $('#wizard').toggle();
});
```

Refer to the [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) website for more information.

This can also be done without JQuery. Using only standard JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
   }
</script>
```

Then add `onclick="toggle_visibility('id_of_element_to_toggle');"` to the button that is used to show and hide the div.

Comment: I do think that the OP is looking for an easier solution than having to use a third-party library (jQuery not tagged). This can be done without JQuery.

Comment: Just a note to the OP: use `visibility: hidden/ visible;` when you don't want the #wizard div to free space for other elements. Use `display: none/ block;` if you want the #wizard div to be hidden with a size, margin & padding properties equivalent to 0 when hidden.

Answer (score 18):

This works:

```js
     function showhide(id) {
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';
     }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>   
    <body>
    
     <a href="javascript:showhide('uniquename')">
      Click to show/hide.
     </a>
    
     <div id="uniquename" style="display:none;">
      <p>Content goes here.</p>
     </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the easy and efficient solution :)

Answer (score 6):

This can't be done with just HTML/CSS. You need to use javascript here. In jQuery it would be:

```
$('#button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //to prevent standard click event
    $('#wizard').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Show and hide div with JavaScript</title>
<script>

    var button_beg = '<button id="button" onclick="showhide()">', button_end = '</button>';
    var show_button = 'Show', hide_button = 'Hide';
    function showhide() {
        var div = document.getElementById( "hide_show" );
        var showhide = document.getElementById( "showhide" );
        if ( div.style.display !== "none" ) {
            div.style.display = "none";
            button = show_button;
            showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
        } else {
            div.style.display = "block";
            button = hide_button;
            showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
        }
    }
    function setup_button( status ) {
        if ( status == 'show' ) {
            button = hide_button;
        } else {
            button = show_button;
        }
        var showhide = document.getElementById( "showhide" );
        showhide.innerHTML = button_beg + button + button_end;
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        setup_button( 'hide' );
        showhide(); // if setup_button is set to 'show' comment this line
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="showhide"></div>
    <div id="hide_show">
        <p>This div will be show and hide on button click</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

The following solution is:

- briefest. Somewhat similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28307880/704972). It's also minimal: The table in the DIV is orthogonal to your question.
- fastest: `getElementById` is called once at the outset. This may or may not suit your purposes.
- It uses pure JavaScript (i.e. without JQuery).
- It uses a [button](http://blogs.html5andcss3.org/show-and-hide-div-with-javascript/). Your taste may vary.
- extensible: it's ready to add more DIVs, sharing the code.

```js
mydiv = document.getElementById("showmehideme");

function showhide(d) {
    d.style.display = (d.style.display !== "none") ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
#mydiv { background-color: #ddd; }
```

```html
<button id="button" onclick="showhide(mydiv)">Show/Hide</button>
<div id="showmehideme">
    This div will show and hide on button click.
</div>
```

Comment: Hmmmm ... TypeError: d is null  when the button is clicked.  How do we get this snippet to work ?

Comment: @MarcoZen It runs fine on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox... Not at home now ... So cant comment on the version. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#btn').click(function() {
     $('#wizard').toggle(); 
 });
```

if you want to begin with the `div` hidden, you should add `style="display:none;"`, like this:

```
<div style="display:none;"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Task can be made simple javascript without jQuery etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showhide() {
document.getElementById("wizard").className = (document.getElementById("wizard").className=="swMain") ? swHide : swMain;
}
</script>
```

This function is simple if statement that looks if *wizard* has class *swMain* and change class to *swHide* and else if it's not *swMain* then change to *swMain*. This code doesn't support multiple class attributes but in this case it is just enough.

Now you have to make css class named **swHide** that has **display: none**

Then add on to the button **onclick="showhide()"**

So easy it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely with html and css and i have.

---

**HTML**
 First you give the div you wish to hide an `ID` to target like `#view_element` and a class to target like `#hide_element`. You can if you wish make both of these classes but i don't know if you can make them both IDs. Then have your Show button target your show id and your Hide button target your hide class. That is it for the html the hiding and showing is done in the CSS.

**CSS**
The css to show and hide this should look something like this

```
#hide_element:target {
    display:none;
}

.show_element:target{
    display:block;
}
```

This should allow you to hide and show elements at will. This should work nicely on spans and divs.

Comment: I like this, the only problem is that it requires the use of an ID. For me, this is problematic because I may have multiple text blocks that are generated dynamically. For a simple static html site though this is good.

Comment: Can someone please explain how to have buttons target IDs/classes?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by making a class with visibility as hidden or display as none and then toggling that class through javascript on the element you wish to.

```js
const para = document.querySelector("div");
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  para.classList.toggle('visibility-toggle')
})
```

```css
.visibility-toggle{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Show/Hide</button>
<div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Click the button above me to hide me.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```