# JQuery- Append to a form in rails based off pick-list selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently have a small form in rails which helps keep track of different detectors that we use at my job. At the top of the form is a pick-list to choose the detector type, and below that are some form fields shared among all of the different detector types that the user fills in.

My question is whether or not there is an easy way in JQuery to append to the end of the main form based on what was selected in the pick-list above so that the unique attributes of a specific detector type can be filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just using the following javascript to toggle visibility of divs instead as well as putting onclick="toggle_visibility('Detector_Type');" in my pick-list field

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function toggle_visibility() {
        var detector = document.getElementById('Detector_Type').value;
        var roic = document.getElementById('ROIC');
        var dcr = document.getElementById('DCR');
        var sub = document.getElementById('Substrate_Material');
        var range = document.getElementById('Optical_Range');
        var register = document.getElementById('Register_Size');
        if(detector === 'GMAPD'){
           roic.style.display = 'block';
           dcr.style.display = 'block';
           sub.style.display = 'block';
           range.style.display = 'none';
           register.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else if(detector === "DFPA"){
           roic.style.display = 'none';
           dcr.style.display = 'none';
           sub.style.display = 'none';
           range.style.display = 'block';
           register.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else{
           roic.style.display = 'none';
           dcr.style.display = 'none';
           sub.style.display = 'none';
           range.style.display = 'none';
           register.style.display = 'none';
        }   
    }
  </script>
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308779/how-can-i-hide-show-a-div-when-a-button-is-clicked)