# How can I show the popup on bottom middle of the page when clicking MapboxGL marker?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker, mapbox-android

I want to show a popup on the bottom middle of the page when clicking a marker.

I have used the following code

```
 new mapboxgl.Popup({ anchor: 'top' })
```

This shows popup on the bottom of the marker. But I want to show the popup at the bottom middle of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popups are more for attaching to the map at some lat/lng, if you want to trigger something to show/hide based on a click, I would create a separate div then show/hide it appropriately and set the text of it as needed.

```
map.on('click', 'mylayer', function (e) { 
  // show or hide your div
  // feature that was clicked would be e.features[0]
} );
```

For the "show or hide your div" part, you could reference:
[How can I hide/show a div when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308779/how-can-i-hide-show-a-div-when-a-button-is-clicked)