# jQuery toggle() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

This question may be asked before. But I cant find the error. Here this is from the video tutorial of new boston.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn').toggle(function(){
    $('#msg').html('yes');
},function(){
    $('#msg').html('No');
});
});
```

The video showing that when click first the div text is **yes** and next time it show **no**
But when I try, when the page loads, the button fadeout and div show **no**. Why? There may be other methods to achieve this functionality. But why this dont work. He showing the syntax of toggle as

```
$('#btn').toggle(function(){code},function{code});
```

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? It's reasonable to expect the same results shown in the video, especially if you're using the same version of jQuery, but when you got a different result did you think to look at the [_.toggle()_ documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)?

Answer (score 12):

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

> Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed
>   in jQuery 1.9. jQuery also provides an animation method named
>   .toggle() that toggles the visibility of elements. Whether the
>   animation or the event method is fired depends on the set of arguments
>   passed.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Updated after OP's comment

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pBdPu/)

if you want to make this code work in any version of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = ['yes', 'no'],
        i = 0;
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        $('#msg').html(arr[i++ % 2]);
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pBdPu/1/)

if you want to make use of `toggle-event` like functionality in future

use [**.one()**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function handle1() {
        $('#msg').html('yes');
        $('#btn').one('click', handle2);
    }

    function handle2() {
        $('#msg').html('no');
        $('#btn').one('click', handle1);
    }
    $('#btn').one('click', handle1);
});
```

**or**

Toggle was [removed in version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed), so you cannot use it - if you want this logic can be manually implemented or you can make use of the [migration plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/)

to include the migration plugin, after the inclusion of jQuery library add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: So how can I achieve the function I intend. Can u Pls modify the above code and give the correct code for jqery 2.1

Comment: tnx i found very helpfull

Comment: @Shameer: if you found the answer useful, accept the answer by clicking the tick underneath the vote arrows to the left of this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, man, you saved my time. I'm refactoring a site with jquery and joomla with mootools and I'm simply cracked my brain... damn