# How do I make an image appear when pressing a button?

Tags: html, css, button

How can I make a button show and/or hide a picture after I've pressed it?

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(http://www.carolyndecristofano.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/iStock_000017124788Large.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
header {
  width: 1906px;
  height: 980px;
  background-image: url(https://stormideaswus.blob.core.windows.net/headerjunction/2014/91/6d2380c6-00e3-4f58-a911-c8aa98afa460.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 78px;
  right: 10px;
}
.button {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 940px;
  background: #34696f;
  border: 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 3.2em/100px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.button {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 78px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button2 {
  display: block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 940px;
  background: #34696f;
  border: 2px solid rgba(33, 68, 72, 0.59);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 3.2em/100px"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(top, #34696f, #2f5f63);
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 0 #1b383b;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
a.button2 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 182px;
  left: 945px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#show {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/iEMr3n4.png) position: relative;
  left: px;
  bottom: 300px;
}
```

```html
<header></header>

<a href="" class="button">Manipulation</a>
<a href="" class="button2">Orgininal</a>
```

[View on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGKJKa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle show/hide div with button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a little javascript like this: https://jsfiddle.net/eye4ytq2/2/

```
<a href="#" onclick="button()" class="button">show</a>
<a href="#" onclick="button2()" class="button2">hide</a>
<div id="show">

</div>
<script>
function button(){
document.getElementById('show').style.visibility='visible';
}
function button2(){
document.getElementById('show').style.visibility='hidden';
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
     $('#show').css('display','block');
 });
 $('.button2').click(function(){
     $('#show').css('display','none');
 });

});
```