# how to hide class on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown

this is my code.
if i click first time i can show div id named as "surveytooldd" . which is disappear before click. but if i click first it it appears but i want to disapper it on second click.

```
<div class="tool survey-tool vertical-center color14" onclick="dropdownmenuHeader(this, event, 'surveytooldd');MM_showHideLayers('surveytooldd','','show');MM_showHideLayers('caption','','hide')">
    <img src="" class="vertical-center">
    <span class="caption vertical-center">Survey Tool</span>
</div>

<ul class="survey-tool-drpdwn" style="visibility: hidden;" id="surveytooldd">
    <li class="survey-tool">
        <asp:LinkButton id="aSurveyTool" runat="server" OnClick="aSurveyTool_Click"><span>Survey Tool</span></asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="poll-tool">
        <asp:LinkButton id="aPollTool" runat="server" OnClick="aPollTool_Click"><span>Poll Tool</span></asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
    <li class="assessment-tool">
        <asp:LinkButton id="aAssessmentTool" OnClick="aAssessmentTool_Click" runat="server"><span>Assessment Tool</span></asp:LinkButton>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a input element and use as flag for secondclick

Comment: use toggle function of jquery

Comment: is it possible with MM_showHideLayers()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle show/hide div with button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button)

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery toggle.

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

This function switches between the states (show and hide) of an element. If the element is currently hidden , it will be shown and vice versa.
More about this [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('class or id').click(function(){
$(#surveytooldd).toggle();
});
```

if you still facing problem than comment below.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
$("#disp").click(function() {
  $("#surveytooldd").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="survey-tool-drpdwn" style="display: none;" id="surveytooldd">
  <li class="survey-tool">
    <asp:LinkButton id="aSurveyTool" runat="server" OnClick="aSurveyTool_Click"><span>Survey Tool</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li class="poll-tool">
    <asp:LinkButton id="aPollTool" runat="server" OnClick="aPollTool_Click"><span>Poll Tool</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li class="assessment-tool">
    <asp:LinkButton id="aAssessmentTool" OnClick="aAssessmentTool_Click" runat="server"><span>Assessment Tool</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
</ul>
<button id="disp">Show Hide</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **"display:none;"** instead of "visibility:hidden;"
and [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) for smooth toggle

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tool survey-tool vertical-center color14" onclick="$('#surveytooldd').slideToggle()">
  <span class="caption vertical-center">Survey Tool</span>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="survey-tool-drpdwn" style="display:none;" id="surveytooldd">
    <li class="survey-tool"><span>Survey Tool</span>
    </li>
    <li class="survey-tool"><span>Poll Tool</span>
    </li>
    <li class="survey-tool"><span>Assessment Tool</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```