# HTML JavaScript hide/show button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a little Ruby on Rails application and I'm trying to add a hide/show button which hides a div with some Id. I've followed the steps from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button) post and it hides the content (second answer). The problem is that the content is not hidden permanently. Once I click in the button, the content dissapears, then the browser do something like an auto refresh and the content appears again.

Could anyone help me with this? It is my first application and my background in javascript is quite poor...

A piece of the code I want to hide/show is the following:

```
<div id='test'>
  <div class="col_4 patients-list">
    <!-- Patients list -->
    <h5>Patients en cours: <%= @patients.size %></h5>
    <div>
      <% @patients_anomaly.each do |patient| %>
        <div class="patient-anomaly"><%= link_to_patient patient %></div>
      <% end %>
      <% (@patients_to_exit - @patients_anomaly).each do |patient| %>
        <div class="patient-to-exit"><%= link_to_patient patient %></div>
      <% end %>
      <% @patients_normal.each do |patient| %>
        <div class="patient-normal"><%= link_to_patient patient %></div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
```

and the javascript of the button is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#test").toggle('hide');
  });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Need too see you're code. So plis add it!

Comment: @Leopard sorry, right now added.

Comment: @N.Smeding sorry, right now added.

Comment: ?? why is your browser refreshing?

Comment: @Fallenhero I don't know. I just click the button and for seconds the content disappears, then, suddenly, appears again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `type="button"` to `button` because default behavior is `submit` which `submits` the page so page is shown in `default state`.

```
<button type="button">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I see that you tagged jQuery, did you try 
`$('#element').hide()` and `$('#element').show()` ?

[Documentation for show](http://api.jquery.com/show/),
[Documentation for hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this `<button>Click</button>`, add this

```
= link_to 'Hide', 'javascript:void(0);', id: 'hideContent'
```

Then in Javascript

```
$('#hideContent').on('click', function(){
  $('#test').toggle('hide');
});
```

This won't reload your page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I wouldn't do `'javascript:void(0);'` just `''` and in JS `preventDefault()`

Comment: Yes, we can do `e.preventDefault()` too, I prefer this.

Comment: yes, this works but is again `Unobtrusive JavaScript`

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id='test'></div>
<button id="hide_show">Click</button>
<script>
  $('#hide_show"').click(function(){
    $('#test').toggle();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please use the [edit] link explain how this code works and don't just give the code, as an explanation is more likely to help future readers.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)