# How to create a drop-down menu in HTML

Tags: html

The assignment I'm working on asks to create a dropdown menu such as the one in the link. How would i do this?

[image]

Comment: You can do something like that using the select tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: you can use a collapse bootstrap has one https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse

Answer (score 5):

You could use `details` and `summary` HTML5 elements (if IE and Opera Mini are not a big concern; for those the below example will fallback gracefully)

```html
<details>
  <summary>Please fill out our optional survey</summary>
  <p>What year are you in college?</p>
  <label><input type="radio" name="clg" value="0"> Not yet there</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="clg" value="1"> Junior</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="clg" value="2"> Senior</label>
</details>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary
http://html5doctor.com/the-details-and-summary-elements/

Find also other ways to  [**Toggle an element**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255513/383904)

---

**To recreate the above in JavaScript** here's a ES6 example:

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-details]')].forEach( el => 
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector(el.getAttribute('data-details')).classList.toggle('hide');
    el.classList.toggle('open');
    el.setAttribute('aria-expanded', el.classList.contains('open'));
  })
);
```

```css
[data-details] {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font: inherit;
}
[data-details]:before      { content: "\25ba"; speak: none; }
[data-details].open:before { content: "\25bc"; speak: none; } 

.hide{ display: none; }
```

```html
<button type="button" data-details="#d1" aria-describedby="d1" aria-expanded="false" >Summary 1</button>
<div id="d1" class="hide">CONTENT ONE</div>

<button type="button" data-details="#d2" aria-describedby="d2" aria-expanded="false">Summary 2</button>
<div id="d2" class="hide">CONTENT TWO</div>
```

Comment: Note that these tags are very poorly supported.

Comment: @Ben Yes. but by providing such answers we can only push vendors to finally implement those new and popular features - meanwhile it fallbacks really gracefully.

Comment: Yes, but Javascript is supported by all browsers, there are *relatively* few issues with compatibility, and it is much more customizable than this built in option.

Comment: The current level of support appears to be pretty good except for IE and Opera mini: https://caniuse.com/#search=summary

Answer (score 0):

As another answer pointed out, you can use the `details` and `summary` elements, but they are poorly supported, only usable in Chrome and Firefox, if you need a solution that works in IE, Edge, and Safari, you need to use javascript, thankfully, this is very simple.

```
<div id="summary" onclick="toggle();">Summary</div>
<div id="togglable" style="display:none;">Toggleable text</div>

<script>
    var i=0;//Counter
    function toggle(){//Function called when Summary is clicked
        if(i%2===0){//Even number
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.display="initial";//Make it visible
        }else{//Odd number
            document.getElementById("toggle").style.display="none";//Visible
        }
        i++;
        if(i===2){
            i=0;//Reset i to ensure it doesn't get too big
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Polluting window scope is a bad idea. A reusable function would be much better by using `addEventListener` and using `data-*` attribute with a target selector. Also using inline JS is considered bad practice.

Comment: Also instead of doing stuff like `if(i%2===0)`, `i++` and `if(i===2){ i=0; }` all you need is `if(++i%2)` or even 1 line instead of 9: `el.style.display = ++i%2 ? "initial" : "none";`but I'd rather go for the computed style property instead of using a global `i`...

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan given that OP likely has very limited Javascript understanding, I decided to allow him an option that is very easy to copy-paste without knowing what it does. Does it represent my best javascript abilities, obviously not, it is meant only to be simple.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan While my code can be simplified, there really isn't any need, preincrementing and ternary operators only serve to add complexity to the solution, this is about intuitiveness for a beginner, not for a oneline-wonder