# How can I change my button to instead of changing a div from visible to not visible, to do the opposite?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a button that changes the visibility of a div. It turns it from being visible to hidden and then back every time it's pressed. How can I make the div stay hidden and make the button show it when it's pressed.

```html
<script>
function Hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
} 
</script>
<button id="Hidden" onclick="Hide()">Click me</button>
<div id="box"> 
 Sample text.
 </div>
```

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for. [How can I change my button to instead of changing a div from visible to not visible, to do the opposite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button#4528100)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle show/hide div with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button)

Comment: As I checked the button is visible and div's CSS property is changing which is working fine.Then what do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Add style to the div - `<div id="box" style ="display: none;">...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

```
CSS - #box{display: none} //this will keep the element hidden on page load

function toggle() {
    var state = document.getElementById("box").style.display;
    if (state === "none") {
        state = "block";
    } else {
        state = "none";
    }
} 

<button id="Hidden" onclick="toggle()">Click me</button>
<div id="box"> 
 Sample text.
 </div>
```

Comment: I'd also improve the code by removing the event handler from the button.
var btn = document.getElementById("Hidden");
btn.addEventListener("click", toggle); // calling the toggle function written above

Answer (score 0):

You can also add `<script>` tag at the end of the HTML code with calling the `Hide()` func
Like this:

```html
<script>
function Hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
} 

</script>
<button id="Hidden" onclick="Hide()">Click me</button>
<div id="box"> 
 Sample text.
 </div>
<script>Hide();</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add the inline display none as below

```html
<script>
function Hide() {
    var x = document.getElementById("box");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
} 
</script>
<button id="Hidden" onclick="Hide()">Click me</button>
<div id="box" style="display:none"> 
 Sample text.
 </div>
```