# Toggle between display of 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to learn jquery and I have 2 div elements that I want only with one button to toggle between hide and show. I tried to write everything that I want but I think the sintax is wrong.

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second">
</div>
<button class="change">change</button>
```

CSS:

```
  #first {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:#ccc;
  }
  #second {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:black;
    display:none;
  }
```

and I wrote as Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
      $('#first').hide();
      $('#second').show();
    });
  });
```

I was thinking about an if else statement however I am not sure if can handle that yet.

Comment: You need a way to check if the div is hidden.  Then, you can toggle if one is hidden or not.

Comment: how can  you see them anyway if they're empty?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [toggle show/hide div with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use toggle method of jQuery. Make your second div hidden on initialisation...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
        $('#first, #second').toggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second" style="display: none;">second</div>
<button class="change">change</button>
```

working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tanaydin/kjyq0eow/3/

documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

edited after: @Darren Sweeney's comment, much better with this selector.

Comment: Wow it was that easy, I understand now! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Done! Sorry did not know that you have to do it.

Comment: not me, you :) and you don't have to. but it is for good karma :)

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you won't see emptys divs.

Example - 1

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
      $('#first').toggle();
      $('#second').toggle();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" style="display: none">teste</div>
<div id="second">teste2</div>
<button class="change">change</button>
```

Example - 2 
You can check if a element is visible with that:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change').click(function() {
      if($('#first').is(":visible")){
      $('#first').hide();
      $('#second').show();
      }else{
      $('#first').show();
      $('#second').hide();
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first">test1</div>
<div id="second">test2</div>
<button class="change">change</button>
```

Comment: You can use `$('#first, #second').toggle();` in your first example

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would i like to suggest a more stable method, so you could add however much "divs". The basic gist of the code is to make a function that iterates from the list obtained. The list consists of the "screen-content" that wants to be alternatively be shown.

```js
const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".screen-content"));
    const previousBtn = document.getElementById("previous-btn");
    const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");
    
    previousBtn.addEventListener("click", showPreviousContent);
    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", showNextContent);
    
    divs.forEach((div, index) => {
      if (index !== 0) {
        div.classList.add("hide");
      }
    });
    
    let currentIndex = 0;
    divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    
    function showPreviousContent() {
        divs[currentIndex].classList.add("hide");
        currentIndex = (currentIndex - 1 + divs.length) % divs.length;
        divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    }
    
    function showNextContent() {
        divs[currentIndex].classList.add("hide");
        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % divs.length;
        divs[currentIndex].classList.remove("hide");
    }
```

```css
.hide{
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="screen-content">first</div>
    <div class="screen-content">second</div>
    <button id="previous-btn" style="height:50px; width:50px"></button>
    <button id="next-btn" style="height:50px; width:50px"></button>
```