# Randomly show / hide images in html by using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i have this div containing two images.

```html
<div class="pc" id="pc1">
  <img src="available.png" alt="Available">
  <img src="unavailable.png" alt="UnAvailable">
</div>
```

when page will load, one image will show and the other will hide. when click on the  image which is shown then the showing image will hide and hidden image will show...   same process for the other image click event. images must be overlap just because i dont want any extra space. same space for both images simultaneously....
how to code for this....

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should start making your hands dirty :) Take some inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528085/toggle-show-hide-div-with-button) and similar questions.

Comment: i tried nothing.... because since 2005...  i didnt do anything on javascript... i forgot js.. i want to use image as a link...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

first of all include jquery in your head tag:

```
<head> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script></head>
```

ok now set an class to the first img and a class to the other img and set for the second image the style to display none

```
<div class="pc" id="pc1">

<img class="img1" src="available.png" alt="Available">
<img class="img2" src="unavailable.png" alt="UnAvailable" 
style="display:none">

</div>
```

now you need to add an script for that:

```
<script>
$( ".img1" ).click(function() {
$( ".img1" ).hide();
$( ".img2" ).show();
 });
  $( ".img2" ).click(function() {
$( ".img2" ).hide();
 $( ".img1" ).show();
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: when page loads both images shown... i want only one image to show after page load...

Comment: i say you need to put in your second img an style of display: none

Answer (score 0):

```html
<style>
  .pc {
    position: relative;
  }
  .visible, .unvisible {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
  .unvisible {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script>
  // add event listener to wait when page is load
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { 
    // get instances of both images
    const img1 = document.getElementById("img1")
    const img2 = document.getElementById("img2")
    /**
     * this method toggle visibility of image
    */
    const toggleImage = (image) => {
      image.classList.toggle("unvisible")
    }
    // hide visible image #1
    toggleImage(img1)
    // show unvisible image #2
    toggleImage(img2)
    // Add event listener for user press a mouse key on image #2
    img2.addEventListener("mousedown, mouseup", () => {
      // hide visible image #1
      toggleImage(img1)
      // show hidden image #2
      toggleImage(img2)
    })
  });
</script>

<div class="pc" id="pc1">
  <img id="img1" src="available.png" alt="Available">
  <img id="img2" class="unvisible" src="unavailable.png" alt="UnAvailable">
</div>
```

so, you can use DOM model to toggle class "unvisible" and hide one image and show other.

Answer (score 0):

Since both your images are children of the same element, you could set an event listener on the parent instead.

```js
const toggleImages = () => {
  // get the parent wrapper element
  const pc1 = document.getElementById('pc1');
  
  // if #pc1 exists
  if (pc1) {
  
    // attach an event click
    pc1.addEventListener('click', () => {
     pc1.classList.toggle('is-active'); // toggle `is-active` class
    });
  }
};

toggleImages();
```

```css
#pc1 {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Hide last image by default */
#pc1:not(.is-active) img:last-child { 
  display: none; 
}

#pc1.is-active img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="pc" id="pc1">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175/000000?text=First+Image" alt="Available">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175/33414D?text=Second+Image" alt="UnAvailable">
</div>
```