# Using the nextSiblingElement in forEach function after clicking again is not working

Tags: javascript

I am practicing making FAQ accordion, I am able to show the answer after

clicking the question but when I am clicking again to hide the answer it is not working.

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions')
const quesArr = Array.from(questions);

quesArr.forEach((ques) => {
  ques.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const next = ques.nextElementSibling;
    hidingAndShowing(ques, next)
  })
})

const hidingAndShowing = (ques, next) => {
  if (next.style.display = 'none') {
    next.style.display = 'block'
  } else if (next.style.display = 'block') {
    next.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="faqAccordian">
  <div class="acc-1 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-1">what is this?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, ipsam velit aut fugiat sit facilis quibusdam illo cupiditate dolorem eius repudiandae sapiente amet obcaecati animi neque odio cumque, quas mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-2 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-2">what does it mean?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat ad tempore quis! Delectus, dolore. Dolorum in distinctio illo similique perspiciatis quia! Error porro id similique, dicta unde blanditiis ducimus laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-3 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-3">what does it do?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus ad reiciendis dolores? Similique numquam est facilis ullam repellendus repellat cum dicta quae fugit. Cupiditate fuga, eum fugiat doloribus quia nisi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-4 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-4">what does it want to do?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perferendis placeat corrupti nam quibusdam est impedit sed optio quia repellendus laborum, ipsa error sapiente culpa consequuntur quaerat nobis incidunt quae.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is showing the nextElementSibling when clicking the first time but on the second time it does not do anything not even throw the error.

Comment: Typo: `=` should be `==` in the `if` condition.

Comment: You don't need `Array.from(...)`. The [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/) from `.querySelectorAll()` already has a `.forEach()` method -> `questions.forEach(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the condition where you are using `if (next.style.display = 'none') {}`.

Technically there are two problems, first is `next.style.display` which gives nothing so instead of that use `getComputedStyle` function to get the value of any property in this case 'display', thats because Computed style contains all the CSS properties set to an element. Even if do not set a property to an element. You will still find that property in the computed styles.

Second is a minor typo in the if condition `=` which should be `==`

Working Example:

```js
const questions = document.querySelectorAll('.questions')
const quesArr = Array.from(questions);

questions.forEach((ques) => {
  ques.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const next = ques.nextElementSibling;
    hidingAndShowing(ques, next)
  })
})

const hidingAndShowing = (ques, next) => {
  if (window.getComputedStyle(next).display == 'none') {
    next.style.display = 'block'
  } else if (window.getComputedStyle(next).display == 'block') {
    next.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="faqAccordian">
  <div class="acc-1 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-1">what is this?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, ipsam velit aut fugiat sit facilis quibusdam illo cupiditate dolorem eius repudiandae sapiente amet obcaecati animi neque odio cumque, quas mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-2 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-2">what does it mean?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat ad tempore quis! Delectus, dolore. Dolorum in distinctio illo similique perspiciatis quia! Error porro id similique, dicta unde blanditiis ducimus laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-3 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-3">what does it do?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus ad reiciendis dolores? Similique numquam est facilis ullam repellendus repellat cum dicta quae fugit. Cupiditate fuga, eum fugiat doloribus quia nisi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc-4 acc">
    <p class="questions ques-4">what does it want to do?</p>

    <p class="answers">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perferendis placeat corrupti nam quibusdam est impedit sed optio quia repellendus laborum, ipsa error sapiente culpa consequuntur quaerat nobis incidunt quae.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help it worked like a charm I was frustrated over it for 2 days but I can progress now.

Comment: I’m glad to hear everything worked out well.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use the [Details Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details).

```css
/* see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details */

details {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: .5em .5em 0;
}

summary {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: -.5em -.5em 0;
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] {
  padding: .5em;
}

details[open] summary {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>what is this?</summary>
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, ipsam velit aut fugiat sit facilis quibusdam illo cupiditate dolorem eius repudiandae sapiente amet obcaecati animi neque odio cumque, quas mollitia.
</details>

<details>
  <summary>what does it mean?</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat ad tempore quis! Delectus, dolore. Dolorum in distinctio illo similique perspiciatis quia! Error porro id similique, dicta unde blanditiis ducimus laborum.
</details>

<details>
  <summary>what does it do?</summary>
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus ad reiciendis dolores? Similique numquam est facilis ullam repellendus repellat cum dicta quae fugit. Cupiditate fuga, eum fugiat doloribus quia nisi.
</details>

<details>
  <summary>what does it want to do?</summary>
  orem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perferendis placeat corrupti nam quibusdam est impedit sed optio quia repellendus laborum, ipsa error sapiente culpa consequuntur quaerat nobis incidunt quae.
</details>
```

---

Otherwise, if you want to target the next immediate sibling you could use the [Adjacent Sibling Combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) `+` in CSS, and use JS purely to [toggle a class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) on the *"button"* element:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".questions").forEach(elQuestion => {
  elQuestion.addEventListener("click", () => {
    elQuestion.classList.toggle("is-active");
  });
});
```

```css
/* Hide answers by default */
.answers {
  display: none;
}

/* Show answer */
.questions.is-active + .answers {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="faqAccordian">
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="questions">what is this?</p>
    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus, ipsam velit aut fugiat sit facilis quibusdam illo cupiditate dolorem eius repudiandae sapiente amet obcaecati animi neque odio cumque, quas mollitia.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="questions">what does it mean?</p>
    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quaerat ad tempore quis! Delectus, dolore. Dolorum in distinctio illo similique perspiciatis quia! Error porro id similique, dicta unde blanditiis ducimus laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="questions">what does it do?</p>
    <p class="answers">
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus ad reiciendis dolores? Similique numquam est facilis ullam repellendus repellat cum dicta quae fugit. Cupiditate fuga, eum fugiat doloribus quia nisi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="acc">
    <p class="questions">what does it want to do?</p>
    <p class="answers">
      Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos perferendis placeat corrupti nam quibusdam est impedit sed optio quia repellendus laborum, ipsa error sapiente culpa consequuntur quaerat nobis incidunt quae.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

To give you some more ideas see: [toggle show/hide div with button?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36255513/383904)